# course content created Event Trigger in Moodle

Tags: php, events, triggers, moodle

I am amateur in moodle. I want to trigger an event when a new course content created by 'modedit.php' file.
For the user created event i used this:

```
include_once($CFG->dirroot.$handlers['user_created']['handlerfile']);
call_user_func($handlers['user_created']['handlerfunction'], $eventdata);
```

But for the course content created what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

moodle provides core events and you can make your own events as well.

core events are on below link.

**https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API**

there is no core event for course content created but it is for course created

**core\event\course_created**

**trigger an event**

```
$params = array('context' => $context, 'other' => array('questionnaire' =>$cm->instance , 'type' => 'u','name'=>'questionnaire_question'));

            $event = \<plugin>\event\data_updated::create($params);
            $event->trigger();
```

data_updated is an event written in my module and it is fired under questionnaire module.

you will need to go thorough event api of moodle.

Comment: how can i make my own event?

Comment: you can make your own event, but to fire that event you have to place it appropriately. as you are talking about course content created then you have to place it from where course content is updated.

Comment: hello again bro. one more question. how can i get the users enrolled in a course in moodle?

Comment: there are many methods to do the same.watch this youtube video for thathttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bo1hX8tVw5U